# How to make a SQL query that would sum multiple records in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, query, table

I've got a large file geodatabase that contains a polyline feature class of water-pipes. The feature class have many fields, but the ones that I'm interested in is that of the water-pipe's **Length** and **Locality Name**.

I'm looking for a way to use the [Table Select](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//000800000007000000) tool to generate a summary table in the same file geodatabase which summarizes the water-pipe's shape lengths for each locality. The output should be file geodatabase table which looks like this example:

1. Locality 1      24395.66118
2. Locality 2      19572.35849
3. Locality 3      17474.87241
4. Locality 4      16205.04598
5. etc...

I've tried to follow this [link](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Using_SQL_for_reporting_and_analysis_on_file_geodatabases/018s0000000t000000/) which describes the SQL syntax for such operation. I didn't get where to write it and how. This is the syntax I probably need from the link:

```
SELECT STATE_NAME, SUM(POP1990) as TotalPopulation
FROM counties
GROUP BY STATE_NAME ORDER BY STATE_NAME
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Summary Statistics GP tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000) for that. Choose Shape_length field to be the Statistics field, and Locality Name field to be the case field.

Comment: This is a good answer but I'm looking for a way to do it by a SQL expression. How can I write a Stand-Alone SQL expression that will edit my data and will give me a new table?

Comment: You cannot do it with out-of-the-box tools for a file geodatabase (SELECT * FROM forms the first part of the SQL expression and is automatically supplied for you, you cannot change this). If you could load your data into a DBMS, then you would be able to execute this query. The page you refer to, is for file gdb API use (or in ArcObjects).

Comment: The most important aspect of file geodatabases is that it **doesn't** have a database behind it.  It *doesn't* support `CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT ...`  The canonical technique for creating a new summary table is to use Summary Statistics.